# How do you select a particular field from a response string which we receive in form of JSON

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, parsing

I have a sample response which I received, the structure is something like this:

```
A = [{ user:
 { score_level: 16,
   is_system: false,
   location: 'Mumbai',
   email: 'abc@xyz.org',
   image: 'example.org',
   firstname: Steve},
details: { solution_count: 1, average_rating: 1, recommendation_count: 0 },
score: 45},
{ user:
 { score_level: 17,
   is_system: false,
   location: 'Miami',
   email: 'ab.org',
   image: 'example.net',
   firstname: Mark},
details: { solution_count: 1, average_rating: 1, recommendation_count: 0 },
score: 50}]
```

We are getting some information about the user, so what I would like to do is to get only the fistname for every user from this file.

I tried using:

```
var read = JSON.parse(A);
var firstname = read["user"]["firstname"];
```

But this dosent seem to work, can you suggest a solution for this?

Comment: What is `items`? I don't see that property anywhere in your JSON.

Comment: I did an edit over it, i tried it with "user".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map through the array of objects, check if the object is a user object, and if so, return the firstname. This will yield an array of firstname values.

```js
const names = A.map((obj) => {
  if (obj.user) {
    return obj.user.firstname;
  }
});
```

Comment: It would be valuable if your answer also explained why the attempted solution wasn't working.